# Make a new DataTable with the same columns as another DataTable

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, datatable

I want to create a new DataTable that has the same columns as another DataTable.

Currently, I do the following:

```
DataTable myTable = new DataTable();
myTable = table.Copy();
myTable.Clear();
```

Then, I import rows into myTable as needed.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?  Right now if table is large, then there is a lot of unnecessary copying of rows going on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to use

```
myTable = table.Clone()
```

Answer (score 10):

Use the Clone method - it creates a copy of the schema (columns) only.
See [DataTable.Clone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.clone.aspx)