# Creating an Instance of a Data Table in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Why is it necessary to recreate the structure (i.e. columns) of an instance of a data table that already has the structure defined?

In VB Studio, I have a datatable (Members) created and defined in dataset (DataSet1).  What I am trying to do is create an instance (dt) of the Members datatable in memory without having to redefine the structure every time with something like:

table.Columns.Add(New DataColumn("ID", GetType(Integer)))

What is the purpose of creating the Members data table in the first place if I have to add the same columns over and over every time?

Comment: What data source are you using (i.e. SQL Server? Access? MySQL?), and do you absolutely have to pre-define your DataTables? I never do. I load a DataTable via an SqlDataAdapter and let ADO.NET automatically add the columns based off the query results.

Comment: Does [Make a new DataTable with the same columns as another DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224926/make-a-new-datatable-with-the-same-columns-as-another-datatable) help?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  Thank you very much!  That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Hardcode I am using a XML file as my data source.

Comment: If you're using XML data sources, there are specific methods already for reading and writing Datatables.  Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.readxml?view=net-5.0